# Flutter - Create dynamic number of texteditingcontrollers

Tags: dynamic, dart, flutter

I am recreating an app I have previously made in Swift, and on one of my pages we call an API and based on the results, we present the user a dynamic number of textfields to search by different search parameters.

Is there any good way to do this in Dart/Flutter? Since dart doesn't support generating code at runtime, is this even a possibility?

Comment: Just use lists or maps to hold the references, no need to generate code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Would you be able to show me how to instantiate a new variable using a map? For instance if I have 3 parameters, I would need 3 texteditingcontrollers.  So I'm trying to think of how I could loop through and create 3 new texteditingcontrollers named textController1, textController2, textController3 for instance.  While keeping this dynamic so I could have any number of them.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm also looking for. Did you manage to solve the problem or found a work around ? @MattLampe

Answer (score 27):

I just modified @Felix's answer with using Map to store TextEditingControllers instead of list. I think its easy to call textEditingControllers with key value pairs. 
Modified code block;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "MyHomePage",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: "MyHomePage",
      ),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var stringListReturnedFromApiCall = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "..."];
    // This list of controllers can be used to set and get the text from/to the TextFields
    Map<String,TextEditingController> textEditingControllers = {};
    var textFields = <TextField>[];
    stringListReturnedFromApiCall.forEach((str) {
      var textEditingController = new TextEditingController(text: str);
      textEditingControllers.putIfAbsent(str, ()=>textEditingController);
      return textFields.add( TextField(controller: textEditingController));
    });

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Column(
              children:[
              Column(children:  textFields),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Print Values"),
                    onPressed: (){
                    stringListReturnedFromApiCall.forEach((str){
                      print(textEditingControllers[str].text);
                    });
                  })
              ]
            )));
  }
}
```

when you write something to textfields and hit to print button results ;

```
flutter: first controller text
flutter: second controller text
flutter: third controller text
flutter: fourth controller text
flutter: so on .......
```

Comment: How do you dispose those TextEditingControllers?

Comment: @override
  void dispose() {
   textEditingControllers.forEach((_,v){
v.dispose();
});
    super.dispose();
  }

Comment: Here how to update textfield value  textEditingControllers[0].text='test'; but it will update controller not textfield any idea about that?

Comment: so you should add textEditingControllers[0] to Textfield's controller property so that textfield recognize the value.

Comment: @LutfiArdiansyah you are welcome, happy to hear that.

Comment: when the input type has change,texteditingcontrol clears itself. is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 11):

More or less as @Günter Zöchbauer mentioned, you can just build a list of widgets which are nested then in a container.

Here's a simple example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "MyHomePage",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: "MyHomePage",
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var stringListReturnedFromApiCall = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "..."];

    // This list of controllers can be used to set and get the text from/to the TextFields
    var textEditingControllers = <TextEditingController>[];

    var textFields = <TextField>[];
    stringListReturnedFromApiCall.forEach((str) {
      var textEditingController = new TextEditingController(text: str);
      textEditingControllers.add(textEditingController);
      return textFields.add(new TextField(controller: textEditingController));
    });

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Column(
          children: textFields,
        )));
  }
}
```

Edit: Added list for `TextEditingController`s to interact with all the `TextField`s

Comment: There is no use of creating local `TextEditingController` without any reference. A `TextEditingController` is commonly used for getting text from TextField and setting text to TextField and these cannot be done with this.

Comment: The `TextEditingController` I instantiate in the example can be used to define the default value of the `TextField` as well as to get the value from itIt's just an example showing how to build a dynamic amount of TextFields, no full implementation.

Comment: @Felix how would you get the values from the textfields created in your example?

Comment: You can iterate through the `textEditingControllers`-list and access the `text` property to read the current value.

Answer (score 6):

Using list of textEditingControllers instead of map

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var stringListReturnedFromApiCall = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "..."];
  List<TextEditingController> textEditingControllers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    stringListReturnedFromApiCall.forEach((String str) {
      var textEditingController = TextEditingController(text: str);
      textEditingControllers.add(textEditingController);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    // dispose textEditingControllers to prevent memory leaks
    for (TextEditingController textEditingController in textEditingControllers) {
      textEditingController?.dispose();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('title'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: stringListReturnedFromApiCall.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: textEditingControllers[index],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

list that contains your controllers

```
     var myControllers = [];
```

function called in order to populate myControllers

> ```
>           createControllers() {
>             myControllers = [];
>             for (var i = 0; i < your_items.length; i++) {
>               myControllers.add(TextEditingController());
>             }
>           }
> ```

init createKeys in your statefullwidget
use it like this, for example in listview builder ;

> ```
> TextField(
>           controller: myControllers[index],
>         ),
> ```

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help you or other's as well.

```
createFieldsList(context) {
    thirdStepUserRegistration.value.forEach((key, value) { //// This line will loop all your data [ValueNotifier<Map<String, dynamic>> thirdStepUserRegistration]
      if (!fieldsController.containsKey(key)) {
        fieldsController[key] = TextEditingController(); //// This one will create you a list of controllers that u need for your fiels [Map<String, TextEditingController> fieldsController]
        fieldsList.add( ////You will be creating a list of widget which is textfields [List<Widget> fieldsList]
          Container(
            height: 40.0,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100,
            child: PrimaryTextFormField( //This is my customize textfield you can create yours
              controller: fieldsController[key],
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
              inputFormatters: textFormatter(),
              hintText: value,
            ),
          )
        );
      }
    });
  }

  Column additionalDetails(BuildContext context) {
    createFieldsList(context);
    return Column( children: fieldsList );
  }
```

Comment: Please, may you add some explanation to improve the comprehension of the solution?