# Flutter : Dynamic Text Field show same value?

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, uitextfield

I have this page as a tab page ,showing mapping data form server ,and contain two text field and bottom for each row to insert them in database ,when i type number in one text filed ,all text fields show same value as shown in image below :

page code :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../models/matchs.dart';
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var logined_user;
  var logined_email;
  TextEditingController _resultController1 = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _resultController2 = new TextEditingController();
  getuser() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    logined_user = preferences.getString('username');
    logined_email = preferences.getString('email');
    if (logined_user != null) {
      setState(() {
        logined_user = preferences.getString('username');
        logined_email = preferences.getString('email');
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    getuser();

    super.initState();
  }
  //App Start
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List matchs = [];
    Future<List> get_matchs() async {
      var url =
          'https://technosat-iq.com/myexpect/api/controller/matchs/show_matchs.php?s_id=1';
      var response = await http.get(url);
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
      for (var x in data) {
        Match newmatch = Match(
          x['s_id'],
          x['week_id'],
          x['league_name'],
          x['home_team'],
          x['away_team'],
          x['home_goals'],
          x['away_goals'],
          x['m_date'],
        );
        matchs.add(newmatch);
      }
      return matchs;
    }
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: get_matchs(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orange[100],
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Loading"),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.indigo[200],
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Active Games',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>((item) {
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Text(item.m_date),
                          Table(
                            columnWidths: {
                              0: FlexColumnWidth(2),
                              1: FlexColumnWidth(2),
                              2: FlexColumnWidth(2),
                              3: FlexColumnWidth(2),
                            },
                            children: [
                              TableRow(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(220, 100, 200, 0.2),
                                  ),
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        height: 50,
                                        child: Text(
                                          item.home_team,
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                        )),
                                    Container(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      height: 50,
                                      child: Image(
                                        image: AssetImage('./assets/flags/' +
                                            item.home_team +
                                            '.png'),
                                        width: 30,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      height: 50,
                                      child: TextField(
                                          controller: _resultController1,
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.grey[700],
                                            )),
                                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.grey[700],
                                            )),
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        height: 50,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                        child: RaisedButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            print(_resultController1.text);
                                            print(_resultController2.text);
                                          },
                                          child: Text('Insert'),
                                        ))
                                  ]),
                              TableRow(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(220, 100, 200, 0.1),
                                  ),
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        height: 50,
                                        child: Text(item.away_team,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                                    Container(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      height: 50,
                                      child: Image(
                                        image: AssetImage('./assets/flags/' +
                                            item.away_team +
                                            '.png'),
                                        width: 30,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      height: 50,
                                      child: TextField(
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                          controller: _resultController2,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.grey[700],
                                            )),
                                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.grey[700],
                                            )),
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                    Container()
                                  ])
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

How can I show the value in one text filed?
Note : when i click on insert the values printed successfully

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the same controllers (`_resultController1` and `_resultController2`) to all the text fields, which makes them share the same value.

Therefore, you need to assign a new controller to each TextField youo generate.

For that, you need to generate as many controllers as you will have text fields, and store these controllers inside some data structure (map, list, etc.), as explained in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54612424/7692859).

Alternatively, if you do not want to mess with controllers, you can create a list/map that will hold the values of the inputs, and use each TextField's `onChange` handler to save the user inputs. Something like:

```
Map<String, String> inputs = {};

//...
//then inside the loop, for each TextField:

child: TextField(
    onChanged: (value) {
        //here for the key I am using e.g. 'MNU-MCI', you cna use anything that is unique to the item
        inputs['$item.home_team-$item.away_team'] = value;
    }   
)

//...
//then, for the corresponding RaisedButton:

child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {
        //now access the input's value using the corresponding key
        print(inputs['$item.home_team-$item.away_team'])
    },
    child: Text('Insert'),
)
```

Comment: How can i using new one inside loop ,i tried to use list of controller but i failed

Comment: Missed that part, in your case maybe you can generate a map that contain your controllers, similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54612424/7692859

Comment: @Salim Or, instead of using controllers, you can store the actual values in a list (or map), and use the text field's `onChange` to get the value, and save it inside that list. I'll try editing the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: your right i made that using onchenge with slider ,same thing i can do it here

Comment: thanks alot ,i solved it by list of controller i will add the answer here

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by convert controller to list.

inside Future builder i made list of controller :

```
for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
              cont1.add(TextEditingController());
              cont2.add(TextEditingController());
            }
```

and in the Text fields i add controller :

```
 child: TextField(
      controller: cont1[int.parse(item.id)],
```

and for second one :

```
child: TextField(
    controller: cont2[int.parse(item.id)],
```

and now it is show as :

[image]