# How to get dynamic multiple textformfield controller value in a listview items using flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, dynamic, textformfield

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijhWq.jpg)

I have a listview n a add Button.every click on Add button one item is generate with textformfield dropdown etc.then if I type something on textformfield it reflect on every item textformfield.how to solve it.

Comment: Hey check this link this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766139/flutter-create-dynamic-number-of-texteditingcontrollers

Comment: not that much helpfull.can you have any other solution